# Get sum of a column of an Excel Apache Poi

Tags: apache-poi

I'm uploading an Excel document from a JSP to a Servlet. I'm using Apache Poi to read the Excel file. My exact requirement is to get the sum of the values of a known column. 
Please tell me if there's a direct way than iterating one by one

Comment: If there's already a cell containing the sum, you can just read it. If not AFAIK, you have to sum up yourself (shouldn't be more than three lines of code).

Comment: yah :) thanks. I was just wondering whether there's a direct command like SUM A or smtn

Comment: Apache POI supports the SUM formula function, and supports evaluating formulas. You could always create a new cell, set it to be `SUM(A1:A900)` (as a random example) then evaluate and read back the result